# Placing 2x3 subfigures side-by-side in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, subcaption, subfig

I need to place 3x2 subfigures side-by-side, but have not been able to come up with a solutions. The thing is, I've done this where I needed 2x1 figures side-by-side, that is, two figures side-by-side. However, here I though the solutions was to add a `\hfill` at the bottom of the subfigure environment, which I've tried for my new graph, but that doesn't work. To illustrate what I mean, what I would like is this:

[image]

such that each "column" of subfigures are its own panel. The code I have used is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h] 
\caption{xx}
\label{x}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{\columnwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\begin{axis}[width=7cm,height=6cm,
            ylabel={Absolute Percentage Error},
            xmin=4,
            xmax=16,
            ymin=15,
            ymax=35,
            xtick=data,
            xticklabel style=
            {/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,rotate=40},
            ytick={15, 20, 25, 30, 35},
            axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
            legend style={fill=gray!5},
            xtick pos=lower,ytick pos=left,
            yticklabel=\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0,zerofill}\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%,
             title style={yshift=-0.21cm,fill=obscureblue,text
             width=5.2cm,text=white,font=\bfseries,align=center},
             title=EV/EBITDA,
]
\typeout{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}}
            \addplot [semithick,mark=square*,black,mark options={scale=1.2}] coordinates {
(4,20)
(6,20)
(8,20)
(10,20)
(12,20)
(14,20)
(16,20)

    };
\addlegendentry{\small{SBP+SARD}}
\addplot[semithick,mark=*,red,mark options={scale=1.2}]
coordinates{
(4,20)
(6,20)
(8,20)
(10,20)
(12,20)
(14,20)
(16,20)

    };
\addlegendentry{\small{GICS+SARD}}    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\\[3ex]
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{\columnwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\begin{axis}[width=7cm,height=6cm,
            ylabel={Absolute Percentage Error},
            xmin=4,
            xmax=16,
            ymin=15,
            ymax=35,
            xtick=data,
            xticklabel style=
            {/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,rotate=40},
            ytick={15, 20, 25, 30, 35},
            axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
            legend style={fill=gray!5},
            xtick pos=lower,ytick pos=left,
            yticklabel=\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0,zerofill}\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%,
             title style={yshift=-0.21cm,fill=obscureblue,text
             width=5.2cm,text=white,font=\bfseries,align=center},
             title=EV/EBIT,
]
\typeout{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}}
            \addplot [semithick,mark=square*,black,mark options={scale=1.2}] coordinates {
(4,20)
(6,20)
(8,20)
(10,20)
(12,20)
(14,20)
(16,20)
    };
\addlegendentry{\small{SBP+SARD}}
\addplot[semithick,mark=*,red,mark options={scale=1.2}]
coordinates{
(4,20)
(6,20)
(8,20)
(10,20)
(12,20)
(14,20)
(16,20)
    };
\addlegendentry{\small{GICS+SARD}}    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\\[3ex]
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{\columnwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\begin{axis}[width=7cm,height=6cm,
            ylabel={Absolute Percentage Error},
            xmin=4,
            xmax=16,
            ymin=20,
            ymax=50,
            xtick=data,
            xticklabel style=
            {/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,rotate=40},
            ytick={20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45,50},
            axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
            legend style={fill=gray!5},
            xtick pos=lower,ytick pos=left,
            yticklabel=\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0,zerofill}\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%,
             title style={yshift=-0.21cm,fill=obscureblue,text
             width=5.2cm,text=white,font=\bfseries,align=center},
             title=P/E,
]
\typeout{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}}
            \addplot [semithick,mark=square*,black,mark options={scale=1.2}] coordinates {
(4,20)
(6,20)
(8,20)
(10,20)
(12,20)
(14,20)
(16,20)

    };
\addlegendentry{\small{SBP+SARD}}
\addplot[semithick,mark=*,red,mark options={scale=1.2}]
coordinates{
(4,20)
(6,20)
(8,20)
(10,20)
(12,20)
(14,20)
(16,20)

    };
\addlegendentry{\small{GICS+SARD}}    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{\columnwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\begin{axis}[width=7cm,height=6cm,
            ylabel={Absolute Percentage Error},
            xmin=4,
            xmax=16,
            ymin=15,
            ymax=35,
            xtick=data,
            xticklabel style=
            {/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,rotate=40},
            ytick={15, 20, 25, 30, 35},
            axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
            legend style={fill=gray!5},
            xtick pos=lower,ytick pos=left,
            yticklabel=\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0,zerofill}\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%,
             title style={yshift=-0.21cm,fill=obscureblue,text
             width=5.2cm,text=white,font=\bfseries,align=center},
             title=EV/EBITDA,
]
\typeout{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}}
            \addplot [semithick,mark=square*,black,mark options={scale=1.2}] coordinates {
(4,20)
(6,20)
(8,20)
(10,20)
(12,20)
(14,20)
(16,20)

    };
\addlegendentry{\small{SBP+SARD}}
\addplot[semithick,mark=*,red,mark options={scale=1.2}]
coordinates{
(4,20)
(6,20)
(8,20)
(10,20)
(12,20)
(14,20)
(16,20)

    };
\addlegendentry{\small{GICS+SARD}}    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

To avoid too much code, I only provided the code for 3 subfigures which are aligned as "panel" A illustrates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h] 
\caption{xx}
\label{x}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering Panel A: aaa
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering Panel B: bbbb
\end{minipage} 
\smallskip

  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\begin{axis}[width=7cm,height=6cm,
            ylabel={Absolute Percentage Error},
            xmin=4,
            xmax=16,
            ymin=15,
            ymax=35,
            xtick=data,
            xticklabel style=
            {/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,rotate=40},
            ytick={15, 20, 25, 30, 35},
            axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
            legend style={fill=gray!5},
            xtick pos=lower,ytick pos=left,
            yticklabel=\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0,zerofill}\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%,
             title style={yshift=-0.21cm,fill=blue,text
             width=5.2cm,text=white,font=\bfseries,align=center},
             title=EV/EBITDA,
]
\typeout{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}}
            \addplot [semithick,mark=square*,black,mark options={scale=1.2}] coordinates {
(4,20)
(6,20)
(8,20)
(10,20)
(12,20)
(14,20)
(16,20)

    };
\addlegendentry{\small{SBP+SARD}}
\addplot[semithick,mark=*,red,mark options={scale=1.2}]
coordinates{
(4,20)
(6,20)
(8,20)
(10,20)
(12,20)
(14,20)
(16,20)

    };
\addlegendentry{\small{GICS+SARD}}    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}%
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\begin{axis}[width=7cm,height=6cm,
            ylabel={Absolute Percentage Error},
            xmin=4,
            xmax=16,
            ymin=15,
            ymax=35,
            xtick=data,
            xticklabel style=
            {/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,rotate=40},
            ytick={15, 20, 25, 30, 35},
            axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
            legend style={fill=gray!5},
            xtick pos=lower,ytick pos=left,
            yticklabel=\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0,zerofill}\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%,
             title style={yshift=-0.21cm,fill=blue,text
             width=5.2cm,text=white,font=\bfseries,align=center},
             title=EV/EBIT,
]
\typeout{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}}
            \addplot [semithick,mark=square*,black,mark options={scale=1.2}] coordinates {
(4,20)
(6,20)
(8,20)
(10,20)
(12,20)
(14,20)
(16,20)
    };
\addlegendentry{\small{SBP+SARD}}
\addplot[semithick,mark=*,red,mark options={scale=1.2}]
coordinates{
(4,20)
(6,20)
(8,20)
(10,20)
(12,20)
(14,20)
(16,20)
    };
\addlegendentry{\small{GICS+SARD}}    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\\[3ex]
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\begin{axis}[width=7cm,height=6cm,
            ylabel={Absolute Percentage Error},
            xmin=4,
            xmax=16,
            ymin=20,
            ymax=50,
            xtick=data,
            xticklabel style=
            {/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,rotate=40},
            ytick={20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45,50},
            axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
            legend style={fill=gray!5},
            xtick pos=lower,ytick pos=left,
            yticklabel=\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0,zerofill}\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%,
             title style={yshift=-0.21cm,fill=blue,text
             width=5.2cm,text=white,font=\bfseries,align=center},
             title=P/E,
]
\typeout{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}}
            \addplot [semithick,mark=square*,black,mark options={scale=1.2}] coordinates {
(4,20)
(6,20)
(8,20)
(10,20)
(12,20)
(14,20)
(16,20)

    };
\addlegendentry{\small{SBP+SARD}}
\addplot[semithick,mark=*,red,mark options={scale=1.2}]
coordinates{
(4,20)
(6,20)
(8,20)
(10,20)
(12,20)
(14,20)
(16,20)

    };
\addlegendentry{\small{GICS+SARD}}    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\begin{axis}[width=7cm,height=6cm,
            ylabel={Absolute Percentage Error},
            xmin=4,
            xmax=16,
            ymin=15,
            ymax=35,
            xtick=data,
            xticklabel style=
            {/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,rotate=40},
            ytick={15, 20, 25, 30, 35},
            axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
            legend style={fill=gray!5},
            xtick pos=lower,ytick pos=left,
            yticklabel=\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0,zerofill}\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%,
             title style={yshift=-0.21cm,fill=blue,text
             width=5.2cm,text=white,font=\bfseries,align=center},
             title=EV/EBITDA,
]
\typeout{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}}
            \addplot [semithick,mark=square*,black,mark options={scale=1.2}] coordinates {
(4,20)
(6,20)
(8,20)
(10,20)
(12,20)
(14,20)
(16,20)

    };
\addlegendentry{\small{SBP+SARD}}
\addplot[semithick,mark=*,red,mark options={scale=1.2}]
coordinates{
(4,20)
(6,20)
(8,20)
(10,20)
(12,20)
(14,20)
(16,20)

    };
\addlegendentry{\small{GICS+SARD}}    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\\[3ex]
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\begin{axis}[width=7cm,height=6cm,
            ylabel={Absolute Percentage Error},
            xmin=4,
            xmax=16,
            ymin=20,
            ymax=50,
            xtick=data,
            xticklabel style=
            {/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,rotate=40},
            ytick={20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45,50},
            axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
            legend style={fill=gray!5},
            xtick pos=lower,ytick pos=left,
            yticklabel=\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0,zerofill}\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%,
             title style={yshift=-0.21cm,fill=blue,text
             width=5.2cm,text=white,font=\bfseries,align=center},
             title=P/E,
]
\typeout{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}}
            \addplot [semithick,mark=square*,black,mark options={scale=1.2}] coordinates {
(4,20)
(6,20)
(8,20)
(10,20)
(12,20)
(14,20)
(16,20)

    };
\addlegendentry{\small{SBP+SARD}}
\addplot[semithick,mark=*,red,mark options={scale=1.2}]
coordinates{
(4,20)
(6,20)
(8,20)
(10,20)
(12,20)
(14,20)
(16,20)

    };
\addlegendentry{\small{GICS+SARD}}    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\begin{axis}[width=7cm,height=6cm,
            ylabel={Absolute Percentage Error},
            xmin=4,
            xmax=16,
            ymin=15,
            ymax=35,
            xtick=data,
            xticklabel style=
            {/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,rotate=40},
            ytick={15, 20, 25, 30, 35},
            axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
            legend style={fill=gray!5},
            xtick pos=lower,ytick pos=left,
            yticklabel=\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0,zerofill}\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%,
             title style={yshift=-0.21cm,fill=blue,text
             width=5.2cm,text=white,font=\bfseries,align=center},
             title=EV/EBITDA,
]
\typeout{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}}
            \addplot [semithick,mark=square*,black,mark options={scale=1.2}] coordinates {
(4,20)
(6,20)
(8,20)
(10,20)
(12,20)
(14,20)
(16,20)

    };
\addlegendentry{\small{SBP+SARD}}
\addplot[semithick,mark=*,red,mark options={scale=1.2}]
coordinates{
(4,20)
(6,20)
(8,20)
(10,20)
(12,20)
(14,20)
(16,20)

    };
\addlegendentry{\small{GICS+SARD}}    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the contribution, that solved my issue! I have run into a small issue now though, and was hoping you could respond - without me having to create a new post entry. How would I go about right aligning the second column of figures, so that they reach my right margin of the page?

Comment: Place \hfill between the left and right subfigures.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: This will change nothign as the width of left and the right subfigure are both `0.5\textwidth`.

Comment: @Philip: You can use ` \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}\raggedleft` for all the subfigures that will show up in the right column.